# Moving common Log4j2 properties into separate yaml file

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I have multiple Log4j2 configuration yaml files.

My question is if it is possible to move the common configuration properties into one yaml file that other log4j2 configurations will use?

The structure is:

```
/resources:
--log4j2-sb.yml
--log4j2-sb-file.yml
```

How would I add ie.:

```
--log4j-sb-common-properties.yml
```

that contains

```
Configuration:
  properties:
    property:
    - name: "com.example.logs.directory"
      value: "/logs"
     .
     .
     .
```

Currently I have added to each yml files the properties, but I would like to separate them.